# Getting the value outside the foreach php loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here is the code used to get the ids of a images in a gallery

```
<?php $images = get_field('photogallery');?>

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <?php echo $image['ID']; ?>
              <?php echo ','; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I get the output

```
 1102 , 3380 , 3348 , 3354 , 3355 ,
```

I would like to get this outside the loop because the result must be used in other shortcode also I see there is a whitespace after every number.

the result must be

```
 1102,3380,3348,3354,3355
```

Please help me.. thanks

Comment: Why not assign the values to a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
<?php echo implode(',' array_column($images, 'ID')); ?>
```

- extract the ID values using `array_column()`
- `implode()` those array values using a comma

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put `<?php ... ?>` everytime everywhere for each statement. Keep in mind that each time you close with `?>` all characters are sent to the client until the next opening `<?php`, that's why you obtain spaces around each comma:

```
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>#
#####<?php echo $image['ID']; ?>#
#####<?php echo ','; ?>#
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*(I changed white-spaces to `#`, this way you can see characters sent to the client (the browser))*.

You can use `array_map` to "filter" only ID items and `implode` to join them , then you only need to store the result in a variable (`$result` here).

```
<?php
$images = get_field('photogallery');
$result = implode(',', array_map(function ($i) { return $i['ID']; }, $images));
echo $result;
?>
```

Now you can use `$result` later everywhere you want.

Comment: I tried but no result. I get  Array,Array,Array,Array,Array

Comment: @ShejuSathyanesan: what returns: `var_dump($images);`

Comment: 'Array (
    [ID] => 2822
    [alt] => 
    [title] => Hot-Air-Balloons-2560x1600
    [caption] => 
    [description] => 
    [mime_type] => image/jpeg
    [type] => image
    [url] => http://acf5/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Hot-Air-Balloons-2560x1600.jpg
    [width] => 2560
    [height] => 1600
)'

Comment: @ShejuSathyanesan: sorry, my fault, it is corrected.